# USB Flash Drive issue

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

I have a PNY 128 GB USB3 flash drive that has stopped working properly.  I had some media files on it and they would not play.  I then tried to delete the files thinking I could re-copy them to the drive.  Not all of the files deleted.  I got the following error: Error 0x8007045D: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."  I am not able to run chkdsk (with the /f flag) on it (returns an error that says the file system is RAW but windows shows it at FAT32).

I have also deleted the partition (in EaseUS Partition Master) and repartitioned and reformatted and the original files that could not be deleted are back.  I did a low level format of the USB drive with HDD Low Level Format Tool 4.40, repartitioned, reformatted and the bloody files are still there.  I cannot delete the file nor can I write any files to the drive.  The drive is NOT flagged as dirty.

Any ideas out there.  I seem to be tapped out on University of Google. :)

Comment: Bin it, get a new one. Flash drives are the floppy disk of the 21st century. Once you get jam in them, throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually how they die. You can try using it on another PC and it may work better. You may also want to try remove all other USB devices first. The idea is that your USB hub may have low power which is causing issues with the flash drive. Also, use a USB port directly connected to your motherboard.